# How can I set back the focalLength value to the post processing settings?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.PostProcessing;


public class DepthOfField : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.GameObject player;
    public PostProcessingProfile postProcessingProfile;
    public bool dephOfFieldFinished = false;
    public LockSystem playerLockMode;

    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private float clipLength;
    private Coroutine depthOfFieldRoutineRef;
    private DepthOfFieldModel.Settings depthOfField;
    private DepthField state;

    void Start()
    {
        if (depthOfFieldRoutineRef != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(depthOfFieldRoutineRef);
        }

        playerAnimator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();

        AnimationClip[] clips = playerAnimator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips;
        foreach (AnimationClip clip in clips)
        {
            clipLength = clip.length;
        }

        DepthOfFieldInit(clipLength);

        state = new DepthField();
    }

    public void DepthOfFieldInit(float duration)
    {
        depthOfField = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;
        depthOfField.focalLength = 300;
        StartCoroutine(changeValueOverTime(depthOfField.focalLength, 1, duration));
        postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = depthOfField;
    }

    public IEnumerator changeValueOverTime(float fromVal, float toVal, float duration)
    {
        playerLockMode.PlayerLockState(true, true);

        float counter = 0f;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            var dof = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;

            counter += Time.deltaTime;

            float val = Mathf.Lerp(fromVal, toVal, counter / duration);

            dof.focalLength = val;
            postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = dof;

            state.focalLength = val;

            yield return null;
        }

        playerAnimator.enabled = false;
        dephOfFieldFinished = true;
        depthOfFieldRoutineRef = null;
    }

    public struct DepthField
    {
        public float focalLength;
        public bool playerCameraLockState;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        SaveGame.Save("depthoffieldstate", state);
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        DepthField state = SaveGame.Load<DepthField>("depthoffieldstate");
        depthOfField.focalLength = state.focalLength;
    }
}
```

At the bottom I added a struct and two functions Save and Load.
In the Save it's updating the state and when saving it's saving the current state so if the focalLength value for example is 1 it will save it in the state the focalLength value as 1.

But in the Load I see in the state that focalLength value is 1 but it's not changing it in the game.
I think that I need somehow to update somehow the settings like I'm doing inside the while loop in the coroutine :

```
postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = dof;
```

But I'm not sure how to do it in the Load function.

Edit :

I did some tests and using a break point I see in the Load function that in the depthOfField the focalLength value is 1 but then I went back to the editor while the game is still running and I see there that in the CC profile file that the value of the focalLength is still 299 and I tried in the editor in the Inspector to change manual with the mouse the focalLength value drag it to the left but I can't it seems like it's locked. Can't change the value.

```
public void Load()
    {
        DepthField state = SaveGame.Load<DepthField>("depthoffieldstate");
        depthOfField.focalLength = state.focalLength;
        postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = depthOfField;
    }
```

This is a screenshot of the CC post processing profile file settings while the game is running after the changes made in the Load funtion :

[image: CC Postprocessing profile settings]

And this is a screenshot where I'm using it in the Player Camera object :
I'm using it with the Depth Of Field script :

[image: Player Camera Depth Of Field CC]

If the game is not running I can change the CC profile values and it does change the blur effect but when the game is running I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Well you assign it to the field `depthOfField`

Simply try to do the same thing as before e.g. in `DepthOfFieldInit` and apply it to the Post-Processing

```
postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = depthOfField;
```

afaik it is a struct so different to a class any changes are not related to the Post-Processing but have to be applied again after every change to the settings.

Comment: I edited my question with what I did and tried and found. It seems like the CC post processing profile file settings properties are locked while the game is running and I can't change them so in the Load funtion focalLength is indeed value 1 but in the editor it's not changing it to 1.